# AS3 asynchronous troubles

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to loop through an array and then fill another array as I do so. However the objects that I am putting into the new array take some time to calculate. This is giving me some scheduling headaches. I created a custom event to account for the completion of that calculation and tried to encorporate that into my loop, however, the function after the loop is still firing before even the first iteration of the loop is complete. Is there anyway to listen for the completion of the loop? Here is my code.

```
package  {

import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import ImageSplitter;
import SplitEvent;
import Displayer;

public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {

    private var _splitter:ImageSplitter;
    private var _imageParts:Array;
    private var _stageHeight:Number;
    private var _imgArray:Array;
    private var _bannerArray:Array = [];
    private var _displayer:Displayer;

    public function DocumentClass() {
        _stageHeight = stage.stageHeight;
        _imgArray = ["banners/banner1.jpg", "banners/banner2.jpg"];
        for (var i = 0; i < _imgArray.length; i++) {
            _splitter = new ImageSplitter(_imgArray[i]);
            _splitter.addEventListener(SplitEvent.SPLIT_COMPLETE, onSplit);
            function onSplit(e:SplitEvent):void {
                trace(e);
                _imageParts = _splitter.imageParts;
                _bannerArray.push(_imageParts);
                trace("Banner len: " + _bannerArray.length);
                _splitter.removeEventListener(SplitEvent.SPLIT_COMPLETE, onSplit);
            }
        }
        afterLoop();
    }



    private function afterLoop() {
        trace("loop finished. Banner len: " + _bannerArray.length);
    }
}
```

Like I said above, afterLoop() fires before even one iteration of the for loop completes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An easier method to do this would be to keep track of the total number of items in _imgArray in a new variable (in the same scope), and decrement it every time onSplit is fired. Once it reaches 0, your loop is finished and you can call afterLoop:

```
public function DocumentClass() {
    _stageHeight = stage.stageHeight;
    _imgArray = ["banners/banner1.jpg", "banners/banner2.jpg"];
    var numImages = _imgArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < _imgArray.length; i++) {
        _splitter = new ImageSplitter(_imgArray[i]);
        _splitter.addEventListener(SplitEvent.SPLIT_COMPLETE, onSplit);
        function onSplit(e:SplitEvent):void {
            trace(e);
            _imageParts = _splitter.imageParts;
            _bannerArray.push(_imageParts);
            trace("Banner len: " + _bannerArray.length);
            _splitter.removeEventListener(SplitEvent.SPLIT_COMPLETE, onSplit);
            numImages--; 
            if (numImages == 0) afterLoop();
        }
    }
    //afterLoop();
}



private function afterLoop() {
    trace("loop finished. Banner len: " + _bannerArray.length);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. I tried something like that earlier, but it wasn't quite there. Either that or I have just been at this too long. I think both haha.

Comment: well this worked for afterLoop(), but now the trouble is that the loop is leaving the onSplit() event handler behind and both _bannerArray elements are getting filled with the same value. Is there anyway to hold up the loop until the SPLIT_COMPLETE event fires? Another way I could see solving it would be to dynamically create instances of the ImageSplitter class, but that is not possible right?

Comment: You might take the function out of the `for` loop, and then within the onSplit function replace where it says `_splitter` with `e.target`, and see if that works.

Comment: I did end up doing something like that and that did the trick. Thanks!